# How to get the correct response (Milliseconds) time of a given URL in Java?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, server, webdriver

How to get the correct response (Milliseconds) time of a given URL in Java?

1. I have created the code listed below but i dont think its receiving the correct response time:

**Objective:**

- Access a Given URL > timer starts
- Once the URL has been established and the correct response code presented > close the connection.

**2. Can anybody advise whether the following code listed below is correct?**

```
    public static void getRepsponseTime(String urlString) throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        HttpURLConnection huc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        huc.setRequestMethod("GET");
        StopWatch pageLoad = new StopWatch();
        pageLoad.start();
        huc.connect();
        pageLoad.stop();
        long pageLoadTime_ms = pageLoad.getTime();
        long pageLoadTime_Seconds = pageLoadTime_ms / 1000;
        long pageLoadTime_SecondsRemainder = (pageLoadTime_ms % 1000);
        System.out.println("Total Page Load Time: " + pageLoadTime_ms + " milliseconds");
        System.out.println("Total Page Load Time: " + "Seconds:" + pageLoadTime_Seconds + ", Remainder:"+ pageLoadTime_SecondsRemainder);
        System.out.println("Status Code: " + huc.getResponseCode());
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
}
```

3. Image example: 
   [image]

thanks for your help!

Comment: What makes you think the response time in not correct?

Comment: Did you try running the code yourself to find out if it's running correctly or not?

Answer (score 0):

Well, think that using Selenium is not the best approach for doing so, however if you need to use it, consider using `BrowserMob proxy` with Selenium, har log entries from proxy do have information you're looking for.

I think it would be better to use tools designed for performance testing, i.e. [JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) or [Gatling](http://gatling.io/) both these tools can give you all the information you may need and some additional info, take a look at reports these tools may generate:

http://gatling.io/docs/2.2/general/reports/

http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html

Comment: thanks so much for your help, lets say i used JMeter would i need to connect with Jenkins to contentiously execute tests? 

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes, you can connect it to Jenkins if you want. I would consider dive deeper on what JMeter and Gatling capable to do, to make sure that it's exactly what you're looking for